# How to downgrade from 15.10 to 14.04

Tags: downgrade

My current Ubuntu version is 15.10 and I'm not satisfied with it... I remember 14.04 to be the most stable and good working version.

Is it possible to downgrade my Ubuntu from 15.10 to 14.04?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Comment: I have been asking some friend the same thing. He said "Downgrading is not standard procedure. " Back-up your data and make clean install.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to downgrade.

You'll have to backup any importand data you consider and fresh install 14.04.

Comment: dugh... :( I knew that
I'm trying out this new 16.04 version.. hope some of the bugs will be fixed