# Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot on Windows 10 on a different partition.  However, due to some reasons I want to install 14.04 instead of 16.04.

Can someone help how to get back from 16.04 to 14.04 dual boot on Windows 10.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version

Answer (score 0):

You can't just downgrade to previous version of Ubuntu.

But you can copy all your files to Windows partition, remove Ubuntu 16.04 partitions from Windows and install Ubuntu 14.04 from LiveCD or WUBI.