# Problems with Ubuntu 16,4

Tags: libreoffice

Upgraded to Ubuntu 16.4 and lost half years work, is it possible to go back to Ubuntu 14?

Comment: you should always backup your personal data, I am using file hosting server and also github for my projects...

Comment: You want your files back or just go back to previous Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

[How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Here's the link that explains some possibilities. But if you are planning to revert back to 14.04 thinking that may help to retrive your lost files back then don't give a try. That won't work. 
Next time be sure to back up your files in external drive before you proceed upgrading your system.

Comment: Link-only answer are not of good quality. please consider expanding your answer.