# How to downgrade from 16.04.1 to 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, downgrade

How do I downgrade or remove the 16.04.1 point release to 16.04?

Comment: The short answer is you don't by I'm still curious about why you want to do that... Please edit and give more details about your issue.

Comment: Is this useful? [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Your question as it stands doesn't make much sense, as it's not clear what problem you are trying to solve. Downgrading is generally not a solution to a problem.

Answer (score 4):

The only practical way to downgrade that I'm aware of is to reinstall, clean, from a pre-point release ISO image.  Obviously, you'll need to make appropriate backups before you proceed.  This will *certainly* be the quickest way, assuming (per comments) that it's a non-production system (i.e. one with little or no user data present, installed just for testing, learning, or certification).

You'll also need to unselect the option to load updates during installation, and turn off automatic updating on the new installation, otherwise the new install with promptly update itself to 16.04.1 again.

Comment: That's not a downgrade, of course.

Comment: It does satisfy the "or remove" part though ;)

Comment: Indeed it does.

Comment: So there is no way by removing the kernels for the point release 16.04.1 to get back to 16.04?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? I have a feeling you fell into the X-Y trap: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: The point release involves far more than just a kernel upgrade.  I'm here to tell you that, at least on my hardware, 16.04 just barely worked (when first installed, the GUI for Kubuntu didn't work at all on my GTx-750 until I changed the video driver from the command line).  Now, it works pretty reliably, though there's a lot of eye candy missing from KDE Plasma that I was used to in 14.04.5.

Comment: I have to certify with Ubuntu 16.04 which I had originally and it got updated somehow to 16.04.1.  If I have to just blow away my machine and start from scratch I can do that, but I just want to find out if there is another alternative to remove the point release ".1" from 16.04.

Comment: I'm new to Ubuntu so any expert advise will be helpful.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that the least time consuming method will be to start fresh, assuming this is a machine installed to learn on or test/certify with rather than a "production" system.

Comment: Thank you Zeiss.  Do you point me to documentation on how I can  turn off automatic updating on the new installation?

Comment: Not at the moment; I'm at work, and my Kubuntu systems are at home.  As I recall, it's a setting in the updater (I also don't use the stock updater, because I was already used to Synaptic when I came to Kubuntu).