# How to remove all packages installed which are not in the repositories and install the current repositories' equivalents

Tags: apt, 16.10, repository, downgrade, 17.04

I mistakenly switched my repositories to Zesty's and upgraded all the packages. Now that I reverted to Yakkety, is there a way I can make apt uninstall all Zesty's packages and reinstall Yakkety's equivalents?

Output of lsblk:

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
 loop0 7:0 0 115M 0 loop
/snap/vlc/4 loop1 7:1 0 78,3M 0 loop  /snap/core/1441
 sda 8:0 0 1,4T 0 disk
 ├─sda1 8:1 0 500M 0 part
 ├─sda2 8:2 0 683,6G 0 part /mnt/Windows 
 ├─sda3 8:3 0 1K 0 part 
 ├─sda5 8:5 0 643,9G 0 part / 
 ├─sda6 8:6 0 7,9G 0 part [SWAP] 
 └─sda7 8:7 0 61,5G 0 part 
sr0 11:0 1 1024M 0 rom
```

Output of uname -a:

```
Linux tommy-S551LB 4.10.6 #1 SMP Tue Mar 28 20:29:54 CEST 2017 x86_64
x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of lsb_release -a:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Zesty Zapus (development branch)
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Doing this *en masse* sounds like a hazardous plan. There's a great deal here that's unclear to me. For one, you state that you've reverted to Yakkety do you mean you've just changed the sources list (repositories)? Did you by any chance make a backup prior to your accidental switch to Zesty repositories? Do you have a backup of your current situation? Please [edit] the output of `lsblk` into your post so that we atleast have some idea of the layout of your system. I'm hoping there's a safer more reasonable approach than what you suggest.

Comment: In future please [edit] information into your post rather than putting it in a comment. Comments can be deleted for various reasons. I've done it for you this time. You'll notice it's a lot easier to read. Thank you for helping us help you! I'm still waiting for answers to the remaining questions I asked [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/898968/how-to-remove-all-packages-installed-which-are-not-in-the-repositories-and-insta?noredirect=1#comment1409076_898968) The best way to receive good answers to your questions here is to respond to requests for information from the team via post [edit]

Comment: @DavidFoerster Added what you asked to the question, thanks for looking into my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how safe it is to automatize such a thing as **reinstalling a massive amount of packages**, so here's a *manual* approach:

Get a list of all the packages from Zesty:

```
apt list --installed | grep zesty > ~/Desktop/packages-to-reinstall.txt
```

Or do instead

```
apt list --installed | grep 17.04 > ~/Desktop/packages-to-reinstall.txt
```

Reinstall them using:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall <package_name>
```

Comment: Hey, I'm confused, I opened packages-to-reinstall.txt but it contains this: ubuntu-wallpapers-zesty/now 17.04.1-0ubuntu1 all [installed,local]

Comment: Yes! That's it, also I issued apt list --installed, the only package which seems to be installed from zesty is that one. How is this possible, the day earlier I had nothing to upgrade, and I upgraded like 2000 packages, I'm not kidding. How is this possible? The "details" built in program says I'm in ubuntu 16.10, but when I get the "ubuntu has experienced an internal error" it says UBUNTU 17.04, screenfetch says I'm on 17.04 too. Is that package particular or something?

Comment: Wait! I just noticed that almost all packages (maybe everyone) has 17.04 in it's name! Example: "unity-schemas/now 7.5.0+17.04.20170301-0ubuntu1 all [installed,local]"

Comment: As you can see, it says 17.04

Comment: This is the output (I deleted the old file):

Comment: Damn, that's a lot of stuff. I tried putting it in this comment but is exceeds the limit by 10288 characters! Zesty definetely wasn't the right keyword

Comment: Try upload it to paste.ubuntu and share a link

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24290901/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall Yakkety from scratch. Release downgrades are unsupported for a reason. See [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](/q/49869/175814).

Comment: I'll upgrade to zesty when the final version is released. If it comes down to this I'd rather wait 2 weeks and let everything get fixed with upgrades than reinstalling and then upgrading

Comment: Yes, that's another worthwhile course of action depending on your needs.