# Is it possible to downgrade?

Tags: 14.04

As I have already  posted here I have a problem with my instalation of ubuntu 16.04 to recognize an  HD where I have all my media.
Just a few minutes ago I tried with  ubuntu 14.04 using live DVD and I could mount that HD and therefore I could see the files and play them.

So my question is : is it possible to downgrade to 14.04 without loosing my configurations or do I have make a fresh install of 14.04 ???

EDIT: I noticed that using live session on 14.04 I can edit the partition, but I think that will have no effect when I return to 16.04 .What do you think ??

Comment: see [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Comment: It's not obvious why it would work in 14.04 but not 16.04. I find hard to believe that a downgrade is the best solution for you. Have you tried a live 16.04 session?

Comment: @Katu: easy to find out - just boot a 16.04 live session and try to mount the partition there.

Comment: @Katu : I have already tried with live session 16.04 and it didn't work.It behaves exactely as my installed version.( I tried first with a live session on 16.04 and next with 14,04 and there's no doubt that it works on 1404 and it don't work on 16.04

Comment: Ask instead how to get your HD recognized and mounted in 16.04. As long as the HD is not defective or broken, it should be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: no.

Generally, you need to do a clean install with a fresh /home in order to avoid the newer version's leftovers breaking the older version.

That said, I got away with restoring the backup of a Kubuntu 14.04 install after an upgrade to 16.04 didn't fully work, and didn't have big issues with stuff 16.04 had changed in my /home -- but *this isn't something you can count on*.  A clean install is the most reliable way to have a fully working installation when you're done.

Comment: Ok so I think I'd better make a fresh install of ubuntu 14.04.What do I have to do in order to keep things as they are concerning the dual boot I have now: 1st option ubuntu - 2nd option when selected windows 10 ??I would like to keep it exactely like that.Do I have to install over ubuntu 16.04 and thats it ??

Comment: Back up anything you've stored in your /home first, then choose the option that lets you select your partitions when you install.  Install to the partition 16.04 has been using, and choose *not* to preserve information in /home (that's why you back it up first).  Installation should update Grub with the same choices you have now, except 14.04 in place of 16.04 (assuming you didn't customize it to get the order you refer to).