# Is it possible to reinstall ubuntu to an older version?

Tags: 16.04, reinstall

I have Ubuntu 16.10 but I want to revert back to 16.04 due to some problems. Is there any way to do this without losing all my data?

Comment: do you have a separate home partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install an older release keeping your `/home`. It is quite easy.

Boot from an Ubuntu installer, select "Install Ubuntu" and choose "something else" option.

You will be prompted to select partitions where you want to install it. If you don't have a separate `/home` partition, select the partition where Ubuntu is currently installed.

## But don't check the format checkbox.

In this case the installer will re-write the system directories, but will keep `/home` intact.

**It is preferable to enter the same user name and password as you had before.**

As aways it is highly recommendable to do a backup first.

If you do have a separate `/boot` partition, you can tell the system to format `/` partition, and just use the existing `/home`.

## Be careful if you don't understand the difference!!!

Comment: I rarely reinstall, didn't know that in a same partition it can keep the home intact. +1, However I always suggest to get a backup first! you don't know what's really going to happen some times. (I'm still not sure if it's fresh or a little bit messy ..., I have to test it I guess ).

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade, but to some extent. As Ravexina said above, separate the Ubuntu installation in 2 partitions: 1st) Ubuntu installation (system files), 2nd) Home folder (/home/)

Also, check these links out (they also state the same things I wrote):

1st Link (AskUbuntu question): [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

2nd Link (Ubuntu Help): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DowngradeHowto

You may want to check this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/891711