# How to downgrade from Ubuntu 16.04.3 to 16.04?

Tags: downgrade

How can I downgrade from 16.04.3 to 16.04?

I want to install Oracle Database 12c (12.1.0.2) on Ubuntu 16.04. The installation guide I refer to exactly Ubuntu 16.04. I'm having trouble running Oracle install scripts and there is an error message that these scripts must run at 16.4 and not 16.04.3 version (as I currently have). That's why I want to downgrade my Ubuntu. I am a new user of Ubuntu and hope you can help me with a light and hassle free proposal and instruction.

I tried to downgrade my Ubuntu 16.04.3 to 16.04, but I would like to know if it is possible and how?

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: I want to install Oracle 12.1.0.2 on Ubuntu. The installation guide I refer to exactly Ubuntu 16.4.
I'm having trouble running Oracle install scripts and there is an error message that these scripts must run at 16.4 and not 16.4.3 version (as I currently have).
That's why I want to downgrade my Ubuntu.
I am a new user of Ubuntu and hope you can help me with a light and hassle free proposal and instruction.

Thanks in advance //Amadeus

Comment: There is no "exactly 16.4", there is "16.04". And it doesn't matter for applications which is the point release.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, it is possible, but you don't want to.

When you're upgrading, your configuration files may change. Packages don't have downgrade scripts, so your package configuration may break when downgraded.

Your best bet is to backup your data, burn a **LiveUSB/CD** and re-install everything.

But, if you really want to downgrade, check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version) link.

Comment: I want to install Oracle 12.1.0.2 on Ubuntu. The installation guide I refer to exactly Ubuntu 16.4.
I'm having trouble running Oracle install scripts and there is an error message that these scripts must run at 16.4 and not 16.4.3 version (as I currently have).
That's why I want to downgrade my Ubuntu.
I am a new user of Ubuntu and hope you can help me with a light and hassle free proposal and instruction.

Thanks in advance //Amadeus

Comment: I suggest doing a fresh install of ubuntu and then restore your backed up files