# Error Installing Scribus on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: kubuntu, scribus

I'm trying to install the current Scribus 1.5.x branch (scribus-ng) on Kubuntu 17.04.

I've seen the following in several places, but I can't get it to work:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scribus/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scribus
```

I get this error each time, even after trying a `--fix-missing`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package scribus-ng is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'scribus-ng' has no installation candidate
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Ubuntu 17.04, and its various flavors, such as Kubuntu, has ended this month.  More documentation on Zesty Zapus can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseNotes).

In order to resolve this, you would need to upgrade your operating system to 17.10.

There are plenty of instructions on how to upgrade your computer - Ubuntu provides a [tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#0) that utilizes the GUI, or you could upgrade via the command line with:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Of course, the usual caveats apply: make sure you back up your data, be mindful of any proprietary drivers that you have and PPAs that you've added, and read the release notes of the OS version you are installing.  There is another [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu#110483) that covers this nicely.

Alternatively, you could 'downgrade' to the 16.04 LTS (which will be supported until April 2021) in order to resolve your issue, but personally I wouldn't recommend this - for your issue an upgrade would suffice.  There is some discussion about this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version).

Comment: So I just did that- or so I thought. Now booting my machine only lets me use a shell. "startx" won't work. It lists my distro as Ubuntu 17.10 (GNU/Linux 4.10.0-42-generic x86_64).

Comment: OR, it seems that sometimes it won't even drop me into the shell. I have a hanging black screen with an underscore in the top left corner.

Comment: **Update:** After some work including a run of dpkg from the root shell, Scribus is now successfully installed in Kubuntu 17.10. Bit of an exhausting round trip, but that's no one's fault. Thanks for the suggestion!