# Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.26-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I was trying to upgrade 14.04 when I started to get dependencies error.

I have read and tried many things to fix the problem, but I always end up getting the error for any of the commands such as:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --fix-broken --fix-missing
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get update (or upgrade)
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

also I have tried commands such as:

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install locales
```

Or

```
$ Sudo apt-cache policy libc6* locale
```

Or

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a

$ sudo apt-get install --fix-broken --fix-missing
```

Gives:

```
(Reading database ... 319648 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc-bin_2.26-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.26-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 triggers ci file contains unknown directive `interest-await'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.26-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading 14.04 to 17.10 isn't supported.

The package you are trying to install requires a more recent version of `dpkg`
 than the one you have. Try to download the .deb package from https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/dpkg and install it using dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -i dpkg_1.18.24ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

(you may need to replace the file name and path). Maybe that works.

Consider doing a fresh install of 17.10.

Comment: Thank you.  Have been trying for sometime.   Cannot install any package.  Broken software system.

Comment: $ sudo dpkg -i dpkg_1.18.24ubuntu1_amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing archive dpkg_1.18.24ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):    cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing: dpkg_1.18.24ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Comment: $ sudo dpkg -i dpkg_1.18.24ubuntu1_amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing archive dpkg_1.18.24ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):    cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing: dpkg_1.18.24ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/dpkg
Resolving packages.ubuntu.com (packages.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.94.203
Connecting to packages.ubuntu.com (packages.ubuntu.com)|91.189.94.203|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘dpkg’

    [ <=>                                   ] 12,914      --.-K/s   in 0.008s  

2018-02-16 18:32:09 (1.48 MB/s) - ‘dpkg’ saved [12914]

Comment: now I am back to the worst situation.   libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.26-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.26-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.26) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is to be installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: locales (< 2.26) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is to be installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) but 2.26-0ubuntu2 is to be installed

Comment: libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) but 2.26-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libgpg-error-dev : Depends: libgpg-error0 (= 1.12-0.2ubuntu1) but 1.27-3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Your answer didn't work.  Please note that I am not trying to upgrade, but to restore the 14.04 back to working condition.  The error posted is encountered due to trying to upgrade (nothing specific to version 17).

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version for some hints about downgrading, they should work in your case with mixed packages from 14.04 and 17.10, too.  But most likely doing a fresh install will be faster and get better results.

Comment: Thanks.  Does fresh install means the loss of data and all programs installed?