# Downgrade make 4.1 to 3.82

Tags: make

I am new to ubuntu.I have a 16.04 LTS ubuntu.I have make 4.1.I need to downgrade it to 3.81 or 3.82.I have tried a lot of solutions but none of them seem to work.

I have tried using the synaptic manager too but it doesnt show force version option.

Comment: you can try checking this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can download make 3.81 (or 3.82, or any other) and install it.

1. Download a [make version in the GNU FTP repository](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/).
2. Extract the files from inside the tar archive to a folder.
3. Go to this folder and install like this (see also [detailed how to install a .tar.gz file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)):

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Comment: I'm leaving this here as info: if you have build errors you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51675200/install-older-version-of-gnu-make-in-ubuntu-18-04  
I tried building it on ubuntu 22.04, which did not work so i built `make` on ubuntu 16.04 using linked answer and copied the binary. 
this gave segfault errors, so this patch was needed aswell:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424919/gun-make-3-82-run-error-on-ubuntu-20-04-segmentation-fault-core-dumped