# Choppy video under Ubuntu18.04 but not Windows

Tags: nvidia, video, vlc, gpu, vga

I have ubuntu 18.04 installed alongside windows 10. This is my pc: https://www.notebookcheck.net/Asus-ROG-GL503VD-DB74-7700HQ-GTX-1050-Laptop-Review.259452.0.html

I have installed proprietary driver for nvida vga (GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2).

vainfo output is as follows:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_0
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.1 (libva 2.1.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Splitted-Desktop Systems VDPAU backend for VA-API - 0.7.4
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG4Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG4AdvancedSimple    : VAEntrypointVLD
      <unknown profile>               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

I just cannot play videos (.mkv, .mp4, etc) smoothly, video runs choppy. In windows runs smoothly. In ubuntu I play with videos and vlc as players with the same result. Interestingly videos in youtube runs smoother than in vlc or videos.

I have checked some previous questions ([Choppy video under Ubuntu but not Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094139/choppy-video-under-ubuntu-but-not-windows))

[How do I enable hardware accelerated video in VLC with Intel HD 4000 GPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240386/how-do-i-enable-hardware-accelerated-video-in-vlc-with-intel-hd-4000-gpu)

however, some are outdated. Thanks for any guide on this.

edit:

free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,7G        2,4G        1,2G        421M        4,0G        4,5G
Swap:          9,8G         93M        9,7G
```

sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii

```
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-435:amd64         435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-435             435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-435:amd64      435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-435:i386       435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-435:amd64       435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-435:i386        435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-435:amd64       435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-435:i386        435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-435:amd64         435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-435:i386          435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-435:amd64           435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-435:i386            435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-435:amd64         435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-435:i386          435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-435         435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-435                  435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-435                435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-435         435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-435         435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                     0.8.8.2                 all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                  390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-435                 435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-435    435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

sudo dmidecode -s bios-version

```
GL503VD.310
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: @heynnema added free -h and sysctl vm.swappiness and dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii and sudo dmidecode -s bios-version as you requested.

Comment: Your BIOS is good. Your mem/swap looks good. If you stop all apps besides Videos/VLC, does it make any difference? You might try a newer Nvidia driver 440.64 available at https://www.geforce.com/drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I got rid of screen tearing on my laptop with Nvidia discrete graphics was switching to Gnome Wayland

You can do so by clicking the gear icon and choosing Wayland when logging into your account.

I utimately ended up disabling Nvidia graphics in the BIOS and switching back to Gnome xorg due to the lack of some features in Wayland and the fact that I didn't plan on using the laptop for gaming.

I didn't have any screen tearing issues on either Wayland or xorg when using Intel's integrated graphics.

If you want to use discrete graphics in unbutu, you should give Wayland a try.