# How to remove 19.10 and go back to 18.04 (black screen of death)

Tags: 18.04, backup, 19.04, reinstall

I had the silly idea of upgrading from 18.04 to 19.10 and all I got was BSOD.

Is there a way to reinstall 18.04 without loosing applications configuration?

I have both /home and /etc backups using Back in Time.

Thanks,

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/

Comment: You'd be better off trying to figure out what's wrong with your 19.10 installation. Have you done a `fsck`? Can you boot to `Recovery Mode` from the GRUB menu? How far does the boot get before you see the black screen? Can you boot with `nomodeset`? What video card do you have... Nvidia? Hit the ESC during boot to watch the boot process.

Comment: It's not possible. Just after update, there was a message suggesting it was better to reboot, so I did. From there on, just black screen of death. Computer is an old HP dv7, stable before upgrade. The Radeon video is not used. I've already downgraded to 18.04, kind of.