# Installing only Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: partitioning

I am using ubuntu 19.04. I want to delete fully and install fresh Ubuntu 18.04. And also I don't want to keep any information ,data inside it.
When I searched in internet for the Installation type that is partitioning part, I became fully confused.
Can you kindly tell me how should I partition hard disk.
Swap partition, home partition, ext4 partition in details.
Remember I don't want to keep neither 19.04 version neither any data in my laptop.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you boot from a LiveUSB and select "Replace Ubuntu..." The installer will do everything for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: what is the default partition taken by ubuntu??

Comment: What do you mean? The installer will create an `ext4` partition for you. Swap partition is not needed. Swap file is used nowadays. If you don't have much knowledge there is no need to tinker with manual partitioning.

Comment: Actually I need to know what does ext4 partition do??

Comment: The answer is easy: `ext4` partition stores files as any other partition. Can you be more specific? If you want to install Ubuntu 18.04 and replace the existing system, installer does it perfectly. It wipes the whole disk and creates all that is needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "what partition do"? A partition is what stores files and directories.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) What does the ext4 partition do? It does everything. One ext4 partition is all you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Answer (score 2):

Default Ubuntu installation options are pretty much all you need.

**Reinstall**, and on the "**Installation type**" step choose:

"**Erase disk and install Ubuntu**"

I used this **default installation** method on my **120GB (111.76GiB) SSD** and the **following partitions** were **created**:

```
$ sudo parted -l

Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   112GB  111GB  ext4
```

**Where**:
**1**. **Boot**/EFI partition ([fat32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32))
**2**. **Root** (/) partition ([ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4)) (for everything else)

**Note**: From Ubuntu 18.04 a swap file rather than a swap partition is used.

With **8GB** of **memory**, the default installation **created** the **following swap file**:

```
$ cat /proc/swaps

Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile               file        2097148 308     -2
```

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5

Comment: I know that I have to choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu." But you all people are like "If someone is giving food then you will take it and never verify why he/she is giving food." My question is what is the default partition taken by ubuntu in details??

Comment: @SukumarJana Because your question was phrased like “give me the food”. If you want to know more, please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1203998/edit) or [ask a new one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: What is the default partition structure taken by ubuntu when selected  "Erase disk and install Ubuntu".

Comment: I updated my answer to include specifics. Do you need more?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific use for Ubuntu, it's pretty safe to just go and use the automatic partitioner with or without LVM (without LVM = easier to restore data).