# How to roll back latest Ubuntu Update

Tags: upgrade, updates, mousepad

I need to roll back the recent Ubuntu upgrade that I did, my PC has become unusable. 
The mouse pad freezes, left and right click buttons chooses to work when they want to.

I did the update after getting a notification on May 1, 2020 and everything doesn't seem right anymore.

How do I roll back this updates??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Comment: None of these links have been able to help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to roll back an upgrade to the older version. You will need to reinstall using the installation media of that previous Ubuntu version.

It is possible to reinstall a previous version without erasing your user data and user configuration data when you use the advanced options of the installer. However, it is likely easiest and most foolproof to just install fresh and copy your user data back into the new installation.