# How to get back from Ubuntu 20.04.3 to Ubuntu 20.04.1 point release

Tags: 20.04, point-release

it is possible to get back to Ubuntu 20.04.1 from 20.04.3 ? I am running Petalinux 2021.1 in Ubuntu 20.04.3 and I get an issue that "This is not a supported OS"

Then I have looked at the reference guide. According to that 20.04.1 is the required OS, not 20.04.3.

https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2021_1/ug1144-petalinux-tools-reference-guide.pdf

```
abc@alpha:/$ uname -a
Linux alpha 5.4.0-88-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 23 17:29:00 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The OS release you're talking about is 20.04, with .1 & .3 only reflecting an indication of what security fixes you have applied to your system, plus **if** you're using the HWE kernel, which kernel that is being used (*there is no change if you've opted to use the GA kernel stack*).  Both 20.04.1 & 20.04.3 are *focal* or the 20.04 release.  You're in effect asking to revert security fixes?  Are you sure that's what you need? or is it just to switch kernel stack choice?  (ie. switch HWE to GA? or GA to HWE?)

Comment: The upgrade from .1 to .3 added security fixes so no you do not roll back to .1 If you were on .1 you have not done updates for quite a while it came out in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Aug 2020

Comment: Then how about this warning in Petalinux 2021.1 "This is not a supported OS" running on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Reinstall of 20.04.1 seems to be the simplest solution, if that's not a problem

Comment: Are there requirements to the kernel stack choice?  Which stack choice have you installed?  If using the GA stack then 20.04.1 & 20.04.3 are using the same kernel (with only security fixes applied), where as if you're using HWE then 20.04.1 & 20.04.3 are using different kernels stacks.... The person who installed your system chose the stack you installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Comment: How to check the kernel stack. I have sudo access on my machine but the installation was done by the IT group. Is it possible to check with sudo which kernel stack I have in Ubuntu 20.04, GA or HWE

Comment: You can check  with `uname -a` and edit your original question to show the result. It will help us find out about your current HWE status. Compare with [The Ubuntu lifecycle and release cadence](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) and scroll down to 'Ubuntu kernel release cycle'.

Comment: This seems like a Petalinux support question to me, and perhaps a bug in their installer. They seem to be treating 20.0.x as discrete releases -- they are not. 20.04 is the release; .x is merely a kernel update and a respin of the installer to include six months of bug patches. It's a (tested) courtesy respin so folks don't need to download additional gigs of updates and bugfixes after installing original 20.04. The [release announcement](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2021-August/000271.html) is quite clear about the purpose of .x LTS updates.

Comment: I have updated my question with `uname -a` but if 20.04 is the release and .x is just a kernel update then I am not sure if I can still run Petalinux 2021.1 in Ubuntu 20.04.3 instead of Ubuntu 20.04.1 which is recommended in the reference guide.

Comment: Your computer has the kernel series 5.4 of the original Ubuntu 20.04 (and 20.04.1) which is also called the GA kernel. This is so even if `lsb_release -a` indicates 20.04.3. Either Petalinux *should* actually work for you, only the test criterion is wrong, ***or*** there is some other program package (not the kernel), that is too new and not compatible. Anyway, I agree with @user535733, that it seems like a Petalinux support question.

Comment: @sbharti This question is not about how to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version. It's about how to roll back Ubuntu to a previous point release, therefore it's not a duplicate of the question that you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot roll back to 20.04.1 but you can download and install the Ubuntu 20.04.1 iso file ([ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso](https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.1/)) from the official Ubuntu website. You can reinstall Ubuntu without losing the data in `/home` even without a separate `/home` partition by following the instructions in the following Ubuntu documentation wikis.

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HomeFolder
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Answer (score 0):

You cannot as such roll back to 20.04.1, but you *can* rollback to the original kernel series that came with the initial Ubuntu version, if you would happen to have enabled HWE. HWE or Hardware Enablement stacks provide newer kernel and X support for existing Ubuntu LTS installations.