# How to install microsoft mysql in 21.10

Tags: upgrade

Last night I upgraded from 21.04 to 21.10 and it removed MsSql-server from my system and there isn't a release for this new version. How can I remove this update so I can get my Sql Server back????

Is there any other way to install mysql without rolling back the update?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/q/49869/1438484) Also... updating your device shouldn't remove packages you installed. If it did, I suggest [filing a bug](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121/1438484). One last thing... why can you not reinstall the package?

Comment: I'm trying to sift through the logs to try and see how/why the app was removed Here is the latest attempt  E: The repository ttps://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2019 hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/source/Sources' as repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2019 focal InRelease' does not seem to provide it

Comment: I'm going to clean up my sources.list and try again.. It was a long frustrating evening and patience was out to lunch. thanks guys

Comment: If you were using a PPA, it would have been disabled during the upgrade. It's possible that PPA is not maintained for 21.10.  Generally if a package is in official repos, don't use a PPA unless you really need a specific version. PPAs can break a system especially if they are not well maintained. See: https://askubuntu.com/q/35629

Comment: This looks like a question for Microsoft (not us): When will MS build their deb repository for 21.10?

Comment: Rolling back the update to install mysql is an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I have edited the question.

Comment: I have more details on the issue.. There isn't a SQL server repository for 21.10 yet adding the 20.04 sql repos I am able to download the .deb package. During install I am getting a dependency error. libc++1 is not going to be installed. libldap-2.4-2 is not installable ***  and libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit ..

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all the feed back and suggestions. After hours of investigating the situation, I have discovered proof that the upgrade did in fact remove SQL Server due to dependency conflicts.

I'm not sure whom to forward the logs to but I do have them ready to send.  I was able to get MSSQL server running finally, after removing libldap2.4-2 and ldap-common excluding dependencies, installing SQL server package with force-depends. downloading libldap2.4 pkg and extracting libs to /usr/lib.

I then ran apt update and upgrade and SQL Server is running again. with no errors.
Excerpt from logs generated during upgrade:

```
Investigating (1) libc++1:amd64 < 1:12.0-52~exp1 -> 1:13.0-53~exp1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libc++1:amd64 Depends on libc++1-13:amd64 < none | 1:13.0.0-2 @un uH > (>= 13~)
Considering libc++1-13:amd64 -1 as a solution to libc++1:amd64 0
MarkKeep libc++1:amd64 < 1:12.0-52~exp1 -> 1:13.0-53~exp1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
Removing libc++1:amd64 rather than change libc++1-13:amd64
MarkDelete libc++1:amd64 < 1:12.0-52~exp1 | 1:13.0-53~exp1 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) mssql-server:amd64 < 15.0.4153.1-6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken mssql-server:amd64 Depends on libc++1:amd64 < 1:12.0-52~exp1 | 1:13.0-53~exp1 @ii umR >
Considering libc++1:amd64 0 as a solution to mssql-server:amd64 -2
 Removing mssql-server:amd64 rather than change libc++1:amd64
MarkDelete mssql-server:amd64 < 15.0.4153.1-6 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Done
```

Comment: can you put some details about removing libldap and ldap-common please...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can manually download the required .deb packages from [here](https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2019/pool/main/a/azdata-cli/) and [here](https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2019/pool/main/m/), and install them with gdebi.

First install gdebi with

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

Then double click the .deb packages to install. Some of them may be dependencies of mysql (gdebi will tell you if there is any missing dependency), and you would have to install those dependencies first.

Comment: Gdebi didn't work either. returns Dependency is not satisfiable: libldap-2.4-2