# downgrade from kubuntu 22.04 to 20.04, keep packages and files

Tags: downgrade

I want to go back to 20.04, keeping my packages and files. I just want to overwrite the system, basically just "roll back" to 20.04. I haven't been able to find a clear answer anywhere. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't downgrade. You'll need to reinstall.  However, I encourage you to ask about whatever problem has made you believe you need to downgrade. This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: Your own backups provide the real rollback capabilities you have, and how are we to know what backup strategy you put in place if you didn't like Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?  There is no *downgrade* path; except from HWE kernel to GA kernel etc within the same release.  You can re-install a system & switch release that way; it's best *forwards* but will also go *backwards* but that requires a lot of homework on the end-user to ensure the older programs can use data files modified by later versions for each app they use; problems are rare but they do exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Comment: I'm involved in QA-testing, and regularly use the same desktop system to QA-test a re-install (*upgrade via re-install*, or *install using existing partition*) to switch to the new release being QA-tested; eg. a recent *impish* I no longer require becomes *kinetic*, or with recent 22.04.1 testing installs move to *jammy*, but they'll become *focal* soon when testing 20.04.5 is done ie. I regularly *bump* releases around (forward & backwards) so I know it's possible, but I've been bitten by it before so I also know the pitfalls (ie. *validating each of your used apps*)

Comment: fyi: the *install using existing partition* documentation can be found [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743) for Lubuntu... it works with Ubuntu Desktop, & all *flavors*, but not server apps as they store *conf* in system directories that get wiped. I've also written answers here but I've written so many I'm not looking for them, including some details on the pitfalls on data issues.  Your own backups are best/easiest by far, but *upgrade via re-install* works well in my experience if you've done your homework